# pyqgis3 atlas feature scale

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, print-composer, atlas

i was create a simple export code using pyqgis3 and atlas print composer map layout on QGIS3.

my question is about map scale.

if i use this line :

```
mapScale = map.scale()
```

i take the scale from map and i can use this number on grid interval as i want.

but after generate atlas mode and using this settings for atlas scale

```
layout.referenceMap().setAtlasScalingMode(QgsLayoutItemMap.Auto)
```

then the map scale change.

i want to take with some way to take the scale from the atlas features after generate or how to use expression on define IntervalX like this .

```
expression123 = "$scale*10"
qgs_layout_item_map_grid = QgsLayoutItemMapGrid("map 1", map)
#qgs_layout_item_map_grid.intervalY(50)
#qgs_layout_item_map_grid.setIntervalX(50)
```

i try to use this but without success.

```
qgs_layout_item_map_grid.dataDefinedProperties().property(QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.intervalY).setExpressionString(expression
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part where you were directly stucked should be related to the following

```py
newGrid = QgsLayoutItemMapGrid ('My new grid', referenceMap)
referenceMap.grids().addGrid(newGrid)
```

You can find below a long correction if you want to use existing grid (if already in your layout) or by adding a new grid

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = manager.layoutByName('mygridname')
referenceMap = layout.referenceMap()

# We supposed you set a grid manually here
firstGrid = referenceMap.grid()
# You can also use referenceMap.grids().asList() if more than one grid

# Else, you can add the grid with
newGrid = QgsLayoutItemMapGrid ('My new grid', referenceMap)
referenceMap.grids().addGrid(newGrid)

# INFO: We continue with `firstGrid` variable but you could
# replace all the following code by using `newGrid` instead

# To get the non dynamic properties for intervalX & intervalY
firstGrid.intervalX()
firstGrid.intervalY()

# To activate the grid
firstGrid.setEnabled(True)

# Your expression as a string
expressionScale = '@map_scale / 100'
# To get the dynamic properties for intervalX e.g QgsLayoutObject.MapGridIntervalX
# & intervalY e.g QgsLayoutObject.MapGridIntervalY
dataDefinedMapGridIntervalX = firstGrid.dataDefinedProperties().property(QgsLayoutObject.MapGridIntervalX)
dataDefinedMapGridIntervalY = firstGrid.dataDefinedProperties().property(QgsLayoutObject.MapGridIntervalY)

# Set the expression
dataDefinedMapGridIntervalX.setExpressionString(expressionScale)
dataDefinedMapGridIntervalY.setExpressionString(expressionScale)

# Activate both properties
dataDefinedMapGridIntervalX.setActive(True)
dataDefinedMapGridIntervalY.setActive(True)
```